# plt: IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, knn

I'm using KNN classifier on this dataset:

[image]

I'm trying to obtain a graph but I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ashutosh/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 3 - Classification/Section 20 - Random Forest Classification/P14-Random-Forest-Classification/Random_Forest_Classification/rft.py", line 38, in <module>
    plt.scatter(x_set[y_set == j, 0], x_set[y_set == j, 1], c=ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

when the following code is run:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
x_set, y_set = x_train, y_train
x1, x2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start=x_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop=x_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start=x_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop=x_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contour(x1, x2, classifier.predict(np.array([x1.ravel(), x2.ravel()]).T).reshape(x1.shape),
            alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(x1.min(), x1.max())
plt.ylim(x2.min(), x2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(x_set[y_set == j, 0], x_set[y_set == j, 1], c=ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label=j)
plt.show()
```

Comment: you could use (separatelly) `print(x_set)` `print( x_set[y_set == j, 0] )`, etc. to see which element makes problem.

Comment: while printing x_set it returns the value of x_train but while printing the latter one, its giving a name error as j is not defined

Comment: @furas do you have any other suggestions

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `j` is defined inside `for`-loop so you have to use it inside `for`-loop.

Comment: @furas thanks for your suggestions,i commented the error as i thought it will keep the question pure, but i couldn't understand what you said about `j`

Comment: error `j is not defined` can means that you use `j` in place where `j` doesn't exists. Usually it is when you create `j` for loop - `for j in ...` - but you use `j` outside loop or in other place.

Comment: if you get `IndexError: too many indices for array` then you should check what you have in array which you use. It seems you expect 2-dimentional array and you use `[i, j]` but array seems to be 1-dimentional and it can use only `[i]` or `[j]`, or maybe it is normal list (not numpy array or pandas dataframe) and it needs `[i][j]`. You can check `print(x_set)`, `print(type(x_set))`, and you can try `print(x_set.shape)`